# String dentro de um modelo no python?

Tags: python

O usuário entra com uma string:`'a123'`
Quero que o programa identifique se essa string esta no modelo
`a%d`, onde %d é um número qualquer.
Preciso identificar qual é o numero tambem.

Answer (score 0):

Se o usuário tiver pouca liberdade de entrada, você pode se livrar do "a" e testar se o resto da string converte em número.

```
texto = "a123"
outro = texto.replace("a","") #substitui 'a' por nada
if outro.isdecimal(): #verificando se a string representa um número
    print("A string {} é um número".format(outro))
```

Se você não tem certeza do tamanho da bagunça que será o input do usuário, terá que trabalhar com [regex](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regex&t=hh&ia=web). Em python a biblioteca usada é a [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). [Este site](https://regex101.com/) é um bom recurso para aprender a utilizar regex e para testar sua busca ao mesmo tempo. Lembre de selecionar a linguagem Python na aba à esquerda.

```
import re
palavra = 'a123'
busca = 'a\d+' #vamos buscar a letra 'a' seguida de um ou mais dígitos
try:
    resultado = re.search(busca,palavra).group()
except: # caso sua busca não esteja na palavra
    print("A string não está no formato aceito")
else: 
    busca = '\d+' # agora queremos só os dígitos
    numero = re.search(busca,palavra)
    print(" O número é {}".format(numero)) # a variavel número é uma string, para usá-la como número use int() ou eval()
```